# Is it illegal to carry a baton?

Tags: united-states, property, weapons

Is it illegal to carry an expandable/extendable baton in the state of Indiana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indiana has no state law against carrying an expandable baton, a.k.a. asp.  (Hard to prove a negative, but [here's one reference in support](http://www.indystar.com/story/news/2014/09/19/guess-weapons-illegal-indiana/15844701/).)  NB: Batons are considered deadly weapons.

*NBB: Laws on these weapons vary tremendously by state, and sometimes even by city, so this answer should not be construed to apply to any jurisdiction outside of Indiana!*

Comment: Not only can the laws vary widely, but enforcement of those laws will also vary, even within individual agencies.